# Async call using Java thread

Tags: java, android

I have two methods in my application, that want to be executed one after other.

```
removeAllNonSyncedData();
getFullDbFromREST();
```

First method is `removeAllNonSyncedData()` which remove all of non sync data from db.

When all data get cleared, I want to execute `getFullDbFromREST()`

```
private void removeAllNonSyncedData() {
        try {

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ContentProviderHelp helper = new ContentProviderHelp();


            ObjectPropertyValueTable ObjectPropertyValueTable = new ObjectPropertyValueTable(helper);
            ObjectPropertyValueAuditTrailTable ObjectPropertyValueAuditTrailTable = new ObjectPropertyValueAuditTrailTable(helper);
            PhotoInfoTable PhotoInfoTable = new PhotoInfoTable(helper);
            PropertyDefinitionTable PropertyDefinitionTable = new PropertyDefinitionTable(helper);

            SyncManagerTable SyncManagerTable = new SyncManagerTable(helper);


            cr.delete(ObjectPropertyValueTable.getContentURI(), ObjectPropertyValueTable.SyncStatus+"<>1", null);
            cr.delete(ObjectPropertyValueAuditTrailTable.getContentURI(), null, null);
            cr.delete(SyncManagerTable.getContentURI(), null, null);
            cr.delete(PhotoInfoTable.getContentURI(), PhotoInfoTable.SyncStatus+"<>1", null);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I execute the second method after first method is done (data cleared completely from database) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is the default case, unless you call the first method asynchronously. Otherwise, methods are always executed one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have already achieve that kind of condition using thread like that
I want to write a file after complete write then i want to Read a file so i make two thread read and write like following manner and user wait and notify function.

```
public  Object isWrite=new Object();
    private class WriteThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            synchronized (isWrite){
                        //Do something as you want
                        isWrite.wait();
        }
}
}

    private class ReadThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            synchronized (isWrite){
                      //Do something as you want                         
                      isWrite.notify();

        }
}
}

        //Calling of write thread then read thread.
        try {
            WriteThread mWriteThread=new WriteThread();
            mWriteThread.start();

            mReadThread = new ReadThread();
            mReadThread.start();

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```